# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы из строки

Tags: python, строки

Имеется строка

```
q = 'Бег 300 м Бег 300 м Бег 300 м'
```

Необходимо удалить повторяющиеся части строки, чтобы получить

```
q = 'Бег 300 м'
```

Пыталась делать через множество:

```
qw = set(q.split())
print(' '.join(qw))
>>> 300 м Бег
```

Но там меняется порядок слов, что не является правильным решением

P.S.
Если имеется строка

```
q = 'Бег 300 м Бег 600 м Бег 300 м'
```

то должно получиться

```
>>> 'Бег 300 м Бег 600 м'
```

Если имеется строка

```
q = 'Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м Бег 300 м'
```

то должно получиться

```
>>> 'Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м'
```

Comment: А если `Бег 300 м Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м`, то что должно остаться? `Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м` или `Бег 300 м Ходьба`?

Comment: Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м

Comment: Похоже, это вариант `проблемы самой длинной повторяющейся подстроки`

Answer (score 3):

Если формат искомых подстрок стабильный "слово число слово", то можно через регулярки решить:

```py
import re

def search(text):
    rx = re.compile(r'\w+\s+\d+\s+\w+')
    return ' '.join(set(rx.findall(text)))

assert search('Бег 300 м Бег 300 м Бег 300 м') == 'Бег 300 м'
assert search('Бег 300 м Бег 600 м Бег 300 м') == 'Бег 300 м Бег 600 м'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
финальный список = []
исходный список разбить на подсписки по 3 элемента, где в состав 3 элементов входит(упреждение дистанция единица измерения)//будем называть каждый такой подсписок тройкой
цикл по исходному списку:
    взять новую тройку исходного списка
    есть ли новая тройка в финальном списке? 
          да  - пропустить тройку, 
          нет - добавить в финальный список

вывести финальный список
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не изучал python, поэтому написал алгоритм на языке который знаю (C#), может натолконет на мысль, или кто-то сможет написать на нужном:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string h_ = "Бег 300 м Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м";
            List<string> l_ = h_.Split(' ').ToList(); // разбиваем на массив
            List<string> j_ = new List<string>(); // список для выражений, которые дублируются
            string search_ = "";
            bool have_ = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < l_.Count; i++) // перебираем все элементы
            {
                if (have_) search_ += $" {l_[i]}"; // если мы ищем строку то добавляем следующее слово
                else search_ = l_[i]; // если нет, то только данное слово будет искаться

                int el_ = Count(h_, search_); // получаем количество вхождений строки
                if (el_ > 1) { have_ = true; } // если больше нуля то продолжаем искать
                else // если нет то проверяем наша строка для поиска больше одного слова 
                { 
                    var g_ = search_.Split(' ');
                    if (g_.Length > 1)
                    {
                        var els_ = g_[..^1]; // выбираем до предпоследнего
                        var str_ = String.Join(" ", els_);

                        ////это как дополнение не обязательно, для удаления 300 м 
                        bool haveinres_ = false; // наличие нашей строки в уже добавленных строках
                        foreach (var in_ in j_)
                        {
                            if (in_.Contains(str_)) haveinres_ = true; // если есть то меняем
                        }
                        if (!haveinres_) j_.Add(String.Join(" ", els_)); 
                        /////////////////////
                    } 
                    have_ = false; 
                }
            }

            string elms_ = String.Join(" ", j_); // все повторяющиеся элементы
            Console.WriteLine(h_);
            Console.WriteLine(elms_);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int Count(string string_, string substring_)
        {
            int i_ = 0;
            int index = 0;
            while (index != -1)
            {
                index = string_.IndexOf(substring_, i_ > 0 ? ++index : 0);                
                if (index != -1) i_++;
            }
            return i_;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Лишние принты можно убрать.  Как-то так вышло. Ждем лучших вариантов.

```
    q = 'Забег 300 м Бег 300 м Ходьба 300 м Бег 300 м Плавание 300 м'
    print(len(q))

    list_ = []
    list_t = []
    total = q.split(' ')
    print('TOTAL', total)

    print(len(total[0]))

    for n in range(len(q)):
        if total != []:
    
            for i in range(3):

                list_.append(total.pop(0))
                print('total', total)
                print('list_', list_)
    
            list_t.append(list_)
            list_ = []
            print('\nlist total', list_t)

    
    for i in range(len(list_t)-1):

        if list_t[i] not in total:
            total.append(list_t[i])
            print('TOTAL', total)
```